# Openlayers 3 - Insert a point into a LineString between somewhere along the Line

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm looking for a smart way to insert a point into a LineString with Openlayers-3. Today, I saved the closest point along the full LineString, made a loop with forEachSegment to find the segment of the closest point and insert the point between start and end of this segment. Finally, I give the new section back into the geometry of the full LineString.

It's working. But any smarter, short solution?

Thanks & Cheers!
Andreas.

```
pp=modifyfeatures.item(g).getGeometry().forEachSegment(function (start, end){
 waylinexy=new Array();
 waylinexy.push(start);
 waylinexy.push(end);
 var segment = new ol.Feature({geometry:new ol.geom.LineString(waylinexy, 'XY')});
 pp.push(start); 
 if (segment.getGeometry().getClosestPoint(cmpos).toString()==cmpos.toString()){pp.push(cmpos); }   
 pp.push(end); 
 return pp; 
});
var ps = new ol.Feature({geometry:new ol.geom.LineString(pp, 'XY')});
modifyfeatures.item(g).getGeometry().setCoordinates(pp);
```

Comment: forgot first line:    cmpos=modifyfeatures.item(g).getGeometry().getClosestPoint(eventcoord);

Answer (score 1):

Looks like foreachsegment is not working with lines with more than one segment. For insering more than one point into a linestring I use this solution now:

```
p=new Array();
cmpos=modifyfeatures.item(g).getGeometry().getClosestPoint(eventcoord);
linegeo=modifyfeatures.item(g).getGeometry().getCoordinates();
for (a=0;a<linegeo.length-1;a++)
{
 start=linegeo[a];
 end=linegeo[a+1];
 var segment = new ol.Feature({geometry:new ol.geom.LineString([start, end], 'XY')});
 p.push(start); 
 if (segment.getGeometry().getClosestPoint(cmpos).toString()==cmpos.toString()){p.push(cmpos); }   
 p.push(end); 
}
modifyfeatures.item(g).getGeometry().setCoordinates(p);
```